# Android 12 able to start foreground activities in the background with ConnectivityManager

Tags: android, foreground-service

I have an `Intent` that was started using `startForegroundService(intent)`

What triggers it is

```
connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(object : NetworkCallback() {
      override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
        startForegroundService(intent)
      }
    })
```

I thought Android12 doesn't let you start foreground services from the background, and this doesn't seem to fall in any [exemption cases](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#background-start-restriction-exemptions). How come the code ran without any issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that your app's `targetSdk` is >= 31? It sounds like it's probably targeting a lower level, and in that case, the background restrictions don't apply.

[Here's](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#foreground-service-launch-restrictions) the actual page from Google, and a direct quote:

> Apps that target Android 12 or higher can't start foreground services
> while running in the background, except for a few special cases. If an
> app attempts to start a foreground service while running in the
> background, an exception occurs (except for the few special cases)

Comment: I think Android 12 is API level 31, but yeah, this code runs on Android 12. The app itself only sets `targetSdkVersion = 29`. Is this the reason why it still works?

Comment: Sorry, I meant 31. And that's correct -- unless targetSdkVersion >= 31, those restrictions don't apply.